# Authentication with If/Else

Tags: php, authentication, cms, login

For keeping the "Administration Panel" secure to those who are logged in, for my web application, is the best practice to use an If/Else Statement?

```
if($_SESSION['logged_in'] == true) {
   include '../styles/templates/admincp/header.php';
   include '../styles/templates/admincp/content.php';
   include '../styles/templates/admincp/footer.php';
}
else {
   include '../styles/templates/login.php';
}
```

Is this how the "professionals' (such as CMS creators, etc) do this authentication style? OR is there a completely better route and method to the If/Else statement to authenticate pages for logged in users to access?

Comment: why can't use isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) ??

Answer (score 2):

At some point, all authentication comes down to an if statement.

- If this user is logged in...
- If this user has manager privileges...
- If this user has admin privileges...
- If this user has connected from an OAuth provider...

There are many methods for including (or excluding) the privileged features:

- Hide the things the user isn't allowed to see
- Don't include a module or control
- Redirect the user to a page that they do have access to

The example code you have posted will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

It comes down to an `if` statement finally somewhere in your code. Personally I've something more similar to this:

```
if ( true === (bool) $_SESSION['user']['login'] && 
     0 < (int) $_SESSION['user']['id'] && 
     time() <= ((int) $_SESSION['user']['last-activity'] + 20 * 60) &&
     $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] === (string) $_SESSION['user']['ip']
     ) {

    /* Update the last user activity time */
    $_SESSION['user']['last-activity'] = time();

    /* Check the permissions, etc. */

    /* Render dashboard */

} else {

    /* Redirect to Login */
    header( 'Location: ' + $cfg->url + '/login/' );
}
```